# JSON to CSV write data to csv file

Tags: json, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I have a small script:

```
require "csv"
require "json"

puts "JSON file name (include extension) ->"
jsonfile = gets.chomp

json = JSON.parse(File.open(jsonfile).read)
#puts json.first.collect {|k,v| k}.join(',')
puts json.collect {|node| "#{node.collect{|k,v| v}.join(',')}\n"}.join

CSV.open("generated.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << json.collect {|node| "#{node.collect{|k,v| v}.join(',')}\n"}.join
end
```

In the terminal it shows like this:

```
Missing: [User],{"error"=>[{"Something"=>"", "errno"=>"somthing", "de"=>"smoehting", "pe"=>"error", "errorMessage"=>"Missing "}], "data"=>nil}
Missing: [User],{"error"=>[{"Something"=>"", "errno"=>"somthing", "de"=>"smoehting", "pe"=>"error", "errorMessage"=>"Missing "}], "data"=>nil}
```

I need to output each row into a seperate row in a csv file. The above is what im trying to do to write it to csv, but it does not work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". When asking about code we need the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem, along with the minimal input data and your expected output. Without those we'll have to write code to test, or cobble up imaginary data based on what it looks like the code wants, or will generate output that isn't related to what you want. Those all lead to inaccuracies and answers that don't directly answer the problem, so we need you to do your part and help us help you and those searching for similar solutions in the future.

Comment: "Does not work" in what specific way?  Does it not write a file?  Write to the wrong file?  Generate a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake in your code is that you call `<<` only one time.  Each `<<` creates one line, so you have to call `<<` method n-times, where *n* is a number of lines.

Your second mistake is that you concatenate the array elements and try to pass a string as a `<<`'s argument. Each `<<`'s argument should be an array.

Summarizing, to create a CSV file containing two lines:

```
# my.csv
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

you should write:

```
CSV.open("my.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [1, 2, 3]
  csv << [4, 5, 6]
end
```

Similarly, to achieve your desired effect, try to rewrite your code as:

```
CSV.open("generated.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  json.each do |node|
    csv << node.collect { |k,v| v }
  end
end
```